# An old inscription

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, story

A tribe that lived here centuries ago called the Rreiorclskl had been very mysterious until now: The only things known about them were that they liked poems, math and puzzles.

However, very recently, an archaeologist who is a friend of yours found a very old inscription written on a rock with a poem that could have belong to them!

Trying to decipher the language the tribe used, the inscription was analized by multiple scientific groups and historians, however, the only things that they were able to find were that the language might have been based on another one.

Years pass, and before your friend can give up on the entire investigation, you decide to give the rock another look.

Here's what is inscripted on it:

```
Sylw, glnaoe, oodoo ltros!
Mnmrnm tp lhe celne heie.
Bet! Daies! Neothiras!
Tte does oihthd...
```

Can you somehow tell what the inscription says and solve the tribe's language? Good luck!

Hint:

> `NO SYMBOLS`

Hint 2 (Big one!):

> `GRID`

Comment: Is this a Rot13(nantenz)?

Comment: It certainly has that look. I haven't so far been able to make it work, though.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Also, if this _is_ a cipher (as the tag suggests), then it's poly-alphabetic ("oodoo") and the sample text is small. I'm not sure that this is solve-able either way.

Comment: I agree. I do not believe there are any words in English that consist of four of the same letter and one additional letter (aaaab, aaaba, aabaa, abaaa, baaaa), so a substitution-only anagram is ruled out by "oodoo".

Comment: Very clever puzzle!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inscription contains

> The first lines of the song Allstar by Smash Mouth

If we namely

> Take all the letters from the inscription (leaving out all punctuation) and put it in a 7x10 grid, we get:
>
> ```
> Sylwglnaoe
> oodooltros
> Mnmrnmtplh
> ecelneheie
> BetDaiesNe
> othirasTte
> doesoihthd
> ```
>
> Now reading the text column by column, we get: "Somebody once told me the world is gonna roll me I ain't the sharpest tool in the sheeed".

We can apply a similar trick to the name of the tribe:

> If we make rows of length 3, we get
>
> ```
> Rre
> ior
> cls
> kl
> ```
>
> which results in the name "Rickrollers"

Comment: Epic. Your archeologist friend has trolled the whole historical community, but not you :)

Comment: Uh, I expected "Never gonna let you down" can be seen by clicking on something?